Changes not showing in local SQL Server Express database after Razor Page form submission
I'm trying to connect to a local SQL Server Express database, but when I submit a form using my .cshtml.cs page, the data doesn’t appear in the table after the command executes. I’m not sure if this is a connection problem or a query issue since I don’t get any error messages.
I read online that sometimes changes might go into the debug folder's database, but I couldn't get their solution to work for me.
Here's the class I use for the database commands:
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

public class DbController
{
    public DbController()
    {
    }

    public void AggiungiUtente(string email, string pass, string ruolo)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DomainDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False"))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string query = "INSERT INTO Utente (Email, PasswordHash, DataCreazione, Ruolo) VALUES (Email, PasswordHash, DataCreazione, Ruolo)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Errore nella connessione :( " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

Here's the Razor Page form:
@page "/aggiungiutenti"
@{Layout = null;}


<!doctype html>
<html class="fixed">
<head>

    <!-- Basic -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Form Layouts | Porto Admin - Responsive HTML5 Template</title>

    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5 Admin Template" />
    <meta name="description" content="Porto Admin - Responsive HTML5 Template">
    <meta name="author" content="okler.net">

    <!-- Mobile Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <!-- Web Fonts  -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800|Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Vendor CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/animate/animate.compat.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" />

    <!-- Skin CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skins/default.css" />

    <!-- Theme Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

    <!-- Head Libs -->
    <script src="vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <section class="body-sign">
        <div class="card-sign center-sign">
            <div class="card-body mt-3">
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="form-group mb3">
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb3">
                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row pb-4">
                        <label class="form-group mb3">Ruolo:</label>
                        <div>
                            <select class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3" name="ruolo">
                                <option style="text-align: center" selected>Amministratore</option>
                                <option style="text-align: center">Utente</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;">Invia </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>

And the cshtml.cs file handling the form:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace DomainManager.Pages
{
    public class AggiungiUtentiModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly DbController _DbController;

        public AggiungiUtentiModel()
        {
            _DbController = new DbController();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost(string email, string password, string ruolo)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _DbController.AggiungiUtente(email, password, ruolo);

                return Page();
            }

            else return Page();
        }
    }
}

I’ve checked my connection string and the code, which should insert the data into the table, but when I check the database, it still shows as empty.
The issue is that even though no errors are thrown, the database doesn’t reflect the changes. The whole things looks pretty simple to me, but I’m not sure where else to look. Any help is appreciated!

Is there any error in your app? Are you sure that you can connect to the database? Maybe you could query that table first to make sure the connection is correct.

where does it get "VALUES (Email, PasswordHash, DataCreazione, Ruolo)"?  What version of .NET are you using here?  I'd suggest injecting the DB context and using LINQ, which is what the standard razor templates would normally do.  The methods you are using here are for old .net framework or core 1.x.

Let's make sure that the connection string is correct, and we could query out the current data table, then try to insert the data. I have a test with codes below and it worked for me.
public IActionResult OnPost(string email, string password, string ruolo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var connection = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebAppxxxxx5BEC;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                
                string query = "INSERT INTO Utente (Email, PasswordHash,  Ruolo) VALUES (@Email, @PasswordHash,  @Ruolo)";
                string search = "select * from Utente";
                SqlCommand selCmd = new SqlCommand(search, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selCmd);
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dataTable);
                var res = dataTable.AsEnumerable();
                da.Dispose();


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PasswordHash", password);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ruolo", ruolo);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Errore nella connessione :( " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return Page();
    }

    else return Page();
}

My table is like below. Then if I use string query = "INSERT INTO Utente (Email, PasswordHash, DataCreazione, Ruolo) VALUES (Email, PasswordHash, DataCreazione, Ruolo)"; but didn't give value to DataCreazione, I would get error. I also need to VALUES (@Email, @PasswordHash,  @Ruolo) instead of VALUES (Email, PasswordHash, Ruolo), otherwize I will get invalid column error.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Utente] (
    [Id]            INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Email]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [PasswordHash]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [DataCreazione] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Ruolo]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


Not working. I checked the connection string under the properties tab. I also removed the DataCreazione just to be sure but nothing appears in the view data.  I basically copypasted @Tiny code and still didn't work.

Pls share a minimal sample for reproducing the issue, so that we could have a test in our side. I used your view and SqlConnection codes, and I fixed the issue in SqlConnection codes to make it work in my side. I can't reproduce your issue now.

I installed the local sql express database and made the ASP.NET Razor project. Got the connection key from the properties of the database and used it in the code the way I showed. I actually also copied your exact code and didn't work

But, I just create a new razor page application, and then use my codes above, I created a new table in my database and then it worked for me. My view could call the Onpost method and pass the 3 variables to the method. Did you get any error message?
